# How to get all relation table with subquery

Tags: mysql, laravel, subquery

I need to make a query where I can get "Place" table, but I have to exclude from that query all "Place" that are already part of the "LocationGroupPlace" table.

I have a class called `Place` and other called `LocationGroupPlace`
each LocationGroupPlace can contain many Places

these are the relations

in  `Place.php` file

```
public function locationGroupPlace()
{
    return $this->hasMany(LocationGroupPlace::class, 'place_id');
}
```

in `LocationGroupPlace.php` file

```
public function place(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Place::class);
}
```

I am trying to retrieve 5 items from "Place" that do not exist in "LocationGroupPlace", that is, the IDs of "Place" are not in the table of "LocationGroupPlace", for example these IDs

[image]

I'm trying to get the first 5 `Place` with all the table from `LocationGroupPlace` with a subquery (for test my subquery)

```
public function getUsedPlacesForGroups()
{
    return Place::with(['locationGroupPlace' => function ($query){
        $query->get();
    }])->limit(5)->get();
}
```

but I can't get `LocationGroupPlace`, the relations section is empty
[image]

Note: `locationGroupPlace` is the function in `Place`

How can I get all `LocationGroupPlace`? **my final idea is to exclude all "Places" included in "LocationGroupPlace"**

Comment: You question is unclear what you actually need? do you need places that don't have any relation in `locationGroupPlace`?

Comment: I need to make a query where I can get "Place", but I have to exclude from that query all "Place" that are already part of the "LocationGroupPlace" table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the places that doesn't exist in `LocationGroupPlace` then you can use [`doesntHave`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence)

```
$places= Place::doesntHave('locationGroupPlace')->limit(5)->get();
```

[See Querying Relationship Absence](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence)